# building Qt under Windows: really with "-platform win32-msvc2017"?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit, configure

I am building qtbase under Windows10. The scarse instructions from Qt and other ressources suggest

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2017 ...
```

Why still 32 and not 64?

Directory `qtbase-everywhere-src-5.11.2` has a subdirectory `mkspecs` that a huger number of platform-specific subdirectories. Among them

```
win32-msvsc
winrt-x64-msvc205
winrt-x64-msvc2017
```

Strangely, `win32-msvsc2017` is not listed there. Does that mean the entire directory `mkspecs` is not used in the `configure` step?

RT = real time = not pertinent for normal desktop applications? [answered in comment by @Ben Voigt]

What are the implications of using `win32-msvsc`:

Does it really build a 32bit library?

Does that entail any restriction for code that uses that library?

Comment: RT stands for "runtime", "Windows Runtime" is the new API that's not backward compatible and has metadata supporting runtime reflection and scripting.  It also mostly provides functions that can't fail with access denied, because they simply aren't capable of requesting privileged operations.  You would only build Qt against WinRT if you are building a WinRT application.

Comment: "win32" does not mean what you think it does.  The term was invented 25 years ago to describe the winapi specific to 32-bit code.  Distinguishing it from the much smaller 16-bit winapi.  No big changes for 64-bit code, only a handful of functions were added.  I suspect that "msvsc2017" was necessary because VS2017 made it quite hard to find stuff back.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Why not merge your two comments into one answer so that we can close this question properly?